# Django - query extracts most frequent values field by field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

i would like to return a single tuple with, field by field, the most frequent values. My models is as follows:

```
class myTable(models.Model):  
        a = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
        b = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
        c = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
        d = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
```

My DB is as follows:

| ID | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 |

The single tuple that I want to return is constitued like that: a=2, b=4, c=1, d=3 (a is 2,3,2 and 1 so the most frequent value is 2). How can I do that?

Comment: what determines the confirmation of a "frequent value"? please add clarification to your question. Does it appear more than n times? or does it seems the most times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

fields = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
field_most_frequent_mapping = {}
for field in fields:
    field_most_frequent_mapping[field] = (
        myTable.objects.values(field)
        .annotate(field_count=Count(field))
        .order_by("-field_count")[0][field]
    )
```

You'll get a dictionary instead of a tuple, but you can work out the rest ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to do 4 separate queries:

```py
from django.db.models import Count
fields = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'

result = [
    {
        field_name: (
               myTable.objects
               .annotate(value=F(field_name))  # rename field for more readable output
               .values('value')
               .annotate(count=Count('value'))
               .order_by('-count')
               .first()
        )
    }
    for field_name in fields
]
```

This will produce following result:

```py
# result
[
    {'a': {'value': 2, 'count': 2}},
    ...
    {'d': {'value': 3, 'count': 2}},
]
```